# An explicit description of the Torelli spaces of pointed genus 2 Riemann surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

In [N], there is a nice and very explicit description of the Torelli space ${\rm Tor}_{1,n}$ of $n$-pointed elliptic curves, for any $n\geq 1$:

$$
{\rm Tor}_{1,n}=\left\{
\big(\tau, (z_1,\ldots,z_n)\big) \in \mathbb H_1 \times \mathbb C^{n}
\; \bigg\lvert \;
\; z_1=0, z_i-z_j\not \in \mathbb Z\oplus \tau \mathbb Z  , \; 
{\rm for } \, i,j=1,\ldots,n, \, i\neq j 
\right\}
$$
where $\mathbb H_1$ stands for the upper half-plane $\mathbb H_1=\{ z \in \mathbb C\, \lvert {\rm Im}(z)>0\, \}$.

**Question (1):** is there a similar explicit description of ${\rm Tor}_{2,n}$ for $n\geq 1$?

---

**Technical details, some questions  and a possible candidate:**
It is known (cf. [H]) that  ${\rm Tor}_{2,0}$ is 
$${\rm Tor}_{2,0}=\mathbb H_2 \setminus \bigcup_{\phi \in {\rm Sp}_2(\mathbb Z)}
\phi(\mathbb H_1 \times \mathbb H_1)
$$
where $\mathbb H_2$ stands for *Siegel upper half space* of   $2\times 2$ symmetric complex matrices whose imaginary part is positive definite: 
$
\mathbb H_2=\left\{ Z\in {\rm M}_2(\mathbb C)\, \big\lvert\,  {}^tZ=Z\, , \;       {\rm Im} (Z)>0\,  
\right\}$.

For $\tau\in \mathbb H_2$, denote by $J(\tau)=\mathbb C^2/(\mathbb Z^2\oplus \tau \mathbb Z^2)$ the associated 2-torus and let $\theta(\cdot,\tau)$ be the associated *Riemann's theta function*  defined by 
$
\theta(z,\tau)=\sum_{N\in \mathbb Z^g} \exp\big(2i\pi \big(\frac{1}{2} {}^tN\cdot \tau \cdot N+{}^tN\cdot z\big)
\big)%\, , \qquad z\in \mathbb C^2.
$ for any $z\in \mathbb C^2$.

For $\tau\in {\rm Tor}_{2,0}$ it follows from Riemann's theorem that  there exists a constant $\kappa(\tau)$ such that the equation
$$
\theta(z+\kappa(\tau)\lvert \tau)=0 \qquad \qquad (\star)
$$
cut out in $J(\tau)$ a Riemann surface $C(\tau)$ whose matrix of periods (for a certain symplectic basis of its homology) is precisely $\tau$.

**Preliminary questions:** 
**(2)** Can the map $\tau\mapsto \kappa(\tau)$ be made explicit? 
**(3)** For $\tau \in \mathbb H_2$ fixed, what is the topology of the subset of 
$\mathbb C^2$ cut out by equation $(\star)$?

Let us consider the set ${\rm Tor}'_{2,n}$ formed by the 
elements $\big(\tau, (z_1,\ldots,z_n)\big) $ of $ \mathbb {\rm Tor}_{2} \times {(\mathbb C^2)}^{n}$ satisfying the two following  conditions:

(i) $\theta(z_i+\kappa(\tau) \, \lvert \tau)=0$   for $ i=1,\ldots,n  $;

(ii) $z_i-z_j\not \in \mathbb Z^2\oplus \tau \mathbb Z^2 $ 
for $i,j=1,\ldots,n, \, i\neq j$.

That is: 
$$
{\rm Tor}'_{2,n}=\left\{
\big(\tau, (z_1,\ldots,z_n)\big) \in {\rm Tor}_{2} \times {(\mathbb C^2)}^{n}
\; \bigg\lvert \;
\substack{ (i) \, z_i-z_j\not \in \mathbb Z^2\oplus \tau \mathbb Z^2 
 \\ 
(ii) \; \;\theta(z_i+\kappa(\tau) \, \lvert \tau)=0
}
\; {\rm for } \, i,j=1,\ldots,n, \, i\neq j  
\right\}
$$

The definition of ${\rm Tor}'_{2,n}$ mimics the one of ${\rm Tor}_{1,n}$ given at the beginning. Maybe it is too naive, but ${\rm Tor}'_{2,n}$ appears as a possible   candidate for the Torelli space 
${\rm Tor}_{2,n}$ (at least to me).

**Precised question (4):** how are related ${\rm Tor}'_{2,n}$ and ${\rm Tor}_{2,n}$?

---

**References**

**[H]** R. Hain, *Finiteness and Torelli spaces*.
Problems on mapping class groups and related topics, 57–70, 
Proc. Sympos. Pure Math., 74

http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0508541

**[NAG]** S. Nag,  *The torelli spaces of punctured tori and spheres*.
Duke Math. Journal 48 (1981), p. 359-388
 
http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.dmj/1077314655